# Fancybox doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

This is my form

```
<form id="detail_form" class="hidden">
...
</form>
```

I have a link

```
<a href='#detail_form' class='btn fancybox detail'> Details...</a>
```

This my script to handle click `a#detail_form`. It works correctly

```
$(".detail").on('click', function () {
    var self = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'details',
        data: {
            id: self.children("input").attr("value")
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == "true") {
            var a = self.children("a").children("span");
            a.html(parseInt(a.html()) + 1);

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Also I call fancybox

```
$(".fancybox.detail").fancybox({
    width: 600,
    autoDimensions: true,
    fitToView: false,
    scrolling: 'no'
});
```

When I clicked `a#detail_form`, my script is starting, but fancybox doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to created HTML to be passed to fancybox then, [Refernce](http://fancybox.net/howto)

You can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".detail").on('click', function () {
        $.fancybox({
            'content': $("#detail_form").html() // Form as HTML Content
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b54uyzey/)

Or you can try like this with your current approach

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".detail").fancybox({
        width: 600,
        autoDimensions: true,
        fitToView: false,
        scrolling: 'no',
       'content': $("#detail_form").html() //Form as HTML Content
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b54uyzey/1/)